# MySQL not start in xampp

Tags: mysql, xampp, port

If in your laptop or desktop already MySQL is install then then it will not start because MySQL run on port number 3306. if already something run on this port then it will not start that why uninstall it and try it.

it is use in xampp for the Database

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make sure that your MySQL can always work. Either stop/uninstall the other application that uses the port of 3306.

OR:

Stop Apache and MySQL

Open:

1. xampp/properties.ini
2. xampp/mysql/bin/my.ini
3. xampp/php/php.ini

change all references to the port of 3306 to the port number of your preference.

Restart Apache and MySQL